# How to detect if touch is released on top of custom Android view?

Tags: android, view, gesture, pressed

When my view is in pressed state and the location of a touch event leaves the view, I want the view to get notified. I also want to get notified when the touch location re-enters my view whilst still in pressed state.

My view extends `View`, and currently implements this method:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    if (!result) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(100).start();
            performClick();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

`gestureDetector` refers to an instance of this class:

```
class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        animate().scaleX(0.9f).scaleY(0.9f).setDuration(100).start();
        return true;
    }
}
```

This works just fine, but when a touch is pressed down and released outside of my view, `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` still gets fired (and thus `performClick()` too), which is not the behaviour I'm looking for. I have tried many other actions in `MotionEvent`, but nothing does this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your if statement to include the dimensions of the button

```
boolean inX == event.getX() >= myButton.getX() && event.getX() <= myButton.getX()+myButton.getWidth();

boolean inY == event.getY() >= myButton.getY() && event.getY() <= myButton.getY()+myButton.getWidth();

if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && inX && inY) {
       // do cool stuff
```

Comment: So you need to go that "low level" for doing it? Kinda strange since you'd think that this would be a pretty essential thing.

Comment: Well after some investigation I'm pretty certain this is the correct answer. Thank you!